# How can i save the name of objects in python in specific order?

Tags: python, image

I am trying to save the name of objects as image in specific order. Like if there are seven objects detected in image and their names are [chair, tv, bed, chair ,bed, chair, chair]. I want that it should be saved as `[chair.png, chair1.png, chair2.png, chair3.png, bed.png, bed1.png, tv.png]`. No matter what objects comes first but its numbers should remains in sequential order respectively. I am trying but is it giving me results like: `[bed.png, bed2.png, chair.png, chair1.png, chair3.png, chair4.png, tv.png]` . I guess i have not setted the count variable correctly but I am unable to find it out

**My code:**

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images
folder_name = 'my_folder_' + time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
os.mkdir(folder_name)
count = 0
for one_mask, bbox, cls, conf in zip(pred_masks_np, nbboxes, pred_cls, pred_conf):
    if conf < 0.25:
        continue
    else:
        label = names[int(cls)]
        print(label) 
        if os.path.exists('/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'+folder_name+'/'+label+'.png'):
            count+=1
            plt.imsave('/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'+folder_name+'/'+label+str(count)+'.png', one_mask, cmap='gray')
        else:
            plt.imsave('/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'+folder_name+'/'+label+'.png', one_mask, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you use the same `count` for all names - but for every name you should have separated `count`

Comment: @furas, could you please post the code how can i do this ?. This is the thing which i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same `count` for all names - but for every name you should have separated `count`.

You could create dictionary at start

```
count = {} # dictionary
```

Inside loop you could check if `label` exists in dictionary

```
        if label not in count:
            count[label] = 0
```

and you could use it to count and generate filename

```
count[label] += 1
name = f'{label}{count[label]}.png'
plt.imsave('/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'+folder_name+'/'+name, one_mask, cmap='gray')
```

---

Something like this:

```
BASE = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'

count = {} # dictionary

for one_mask, bbox, cls, conf in zip(pred_masks_np, nbboxes, pred_cls, pred_conf):
    if conf < 0.25:
        continue
    else:
        label = names[int(cls)]
        print(label)
        
        if label not in count:
            count[label] = 0
            
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE, folder_name, f'{label}.png')):
            count[label] += 1
            name = f'{label}{count[label]}.png'
        else:
            name = f'{label}png'

        plt.imsave(os.path.join(BASE, folder_name, name), one_mask, cmap='gray')
```

---

You could even use `count` instead of `exists`

```
BASE = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Now_fine/yolov7-mask/binary_masks_images/'
count = {} # dictionary

for one_mask, bbox, cls, conf in zip(pred_masks_np, nbboxes, pred_cls, pred_conf):
    if conf < 0.25:
        continue
    else:
        label = names[int(cls)]
        print(label)
        
        if label not in count:
            count[label] = 0
            
        if count[label] == 0:
            name = f'{label}png'
        else:
            name = f'{label}{count[label]}.png'

        plt.imsave(os.path.join(BASE, folder_name, name), one_mask, cmap='gray')
        
        count[label] += 1
```

---

Frankly I would start names with `0` - `chair0.png`, `bed0.png`, etc. Or I would use `1` for first image - `chair1.png` instead of `chair.png`

This way all code would be simpler.

If you use many images then I would use names like `chair001.png` to keep order - because Python (and system) will sort string `"10"` before `"2"`, but it will keep order if you use `"02"`

```
# use :03 to get 3 digits filled with `0` - like `002`

name = f'{label}{count[label]:03}.png'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Absolutely brilliant, dont know how to say thanks.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer if i need dictionary which posses multiple dics like this ,    1:{
       key:'chair',
       coordinates : [ ],
     },
     2:{
       key:'bowl',
      coordinates : [ ],
     },

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not counting different items, but incrementing the counter for every new item. One option would be to keep different counts in a dictionary e.g. `item_counts = {'chair': 0, 'bed': 1, 'tv': 0}` or sort the source data so that items always come in correct order. Other solution would be to count the existing items with a helper functions such as this before saving:

```
def count_files(filename):
    dir_path = r'.'
    count = 0
    for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)) and filename in path:
            count += 1
    return count

# Counts files with word 'bed' in name
print(count_files('bed'))
```